# Issues installing PHP on an Apache server

Tags: php, apache, soap

I am trying to install PHP locally so I can run PHP files. The problem is that I am not able to install it properly although I am trying to follow the instructions. So I am following the instructions provided in this site for example:

http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2009/04/13/how-to-install-php-on-windows/

and I can't find the file: \conf\httpd.conf

Not sure how to proceed. Also, is there a simpler way to install PHP.

I am using Apache 6.x on Windows Server 2008. I am trying to install PHP 5.2.x and the reason i am doing this is because I want to set up a SOAP server in order to make calls to a internal server from an external source.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Yeah, I am not sure this is the right version but that what it shows when I click on release notes: Apache Tomcat Version 6.0.14

Comment: Ohh I see, is there a way to install PHP on tomcat (an easy way or at least a tutorial?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as an answer rather than a comment.

I did not know there was an Apache 6.x version, are you using Tomcat? If so, that tutorial is for the Apache 2.x HTTP Server, not Tomcat, you would need to find one for Tomcat ( <s>Installing PHP5 on Tomcat on Windows Tutorial</s> )

EDIT: Removed the bad link.

Comment: The tutorial has missing links that are important to the install, I will try my best to look around it and will let you know what happens. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Well, depending on your needs, I never used Tomcat, so I do not know if that is possible, but you can install PHP to work on IIS (if you are using IIS). This should be trivial and plenty of information on it: http://www.microsoft.com/showcase/en/us/details/7293e003-91c5-4e50-a3c9-ff47b3c62bbc

But yea, it depends on your needs, if you need it to be independent of IIS, Apache HTTP Server 2.x may be what you want to look into installing.

Answer (score 0):

You want to try the XAMPP package: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html.

Also, make sure to that apache is installed properly.  You have to re start it, before testing the php.